# Cakephp 3 - Select input field has no ID - How to get date with JQuery

Tags: jquery, date, cakephp, input

I've written a form using the form helper.
The date input field looks like this :

```
<select name="pilot_med_certs[due_date][day]">
<select name="pilot_med_certs[due_date][month]">
<select name="pilot_med_certs[due_date][year]">
```

The issue is that it has no ID attribute ( even that I pass the  ['id' => 'id-of-the-select-input'] in the options array ).
How do I set the ID attribute ?

In the meanwhile I can get the values as this :

```
var o = $('select[name="pilot_med_certs[due_date][day]"]').val();
```

Thanks.
Regards.
Facundo.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-datetime-inputs)

```
echo $this->Form->date(
'test', 
[
    'day' => ['id' => 'day-id'],
    'month' => ['id' => 'month-id'],
    'year' => ['id' => 'year-id']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a datepicker library like jquery datepicker (google it) do to date input, that will avoid you some problems like bissextile years.

If you really want to do 3 selects for day/month/year, you should do like this:

In your view:

```
$days = [1,2,3,...];

//in your form
echo $this->Form->select('day',$days, ['id' => 'days']);
```

Doc: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers

Then in your jquery:

```
$('#days').change(function(){
    var days = $('#days option:selected').text();
});
```

Doc: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/